# Google login - Login Stuck after pressing continue

Tags: swift, google-signin

Working on a MacOS app when I click Sign in to Google, the popup shows up correctly. However when I click continue nothing happens.

I'm using the Google sign in from the Swift Package Manager

```
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance.signIn
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. Turns out that one of my Macs that I was testing on was V12.2 and it needed to be at least v12.4 for the login to work.